# Understanding the etale space construction from a formal viewpoint

Tags: ct.category-theory, sheaf-theory

Suppose I have a topological space $X$. Let $\mathcal{O}(X)$ denote the poset of open subsets. There is a canonical functor $\mathcal{O}(X) \to Top/X$ which sends an open $U \in \mathcal{O}(X)$ to $U \hookrightarrow X$. By left-Kan extension, this produces an adjunction between $Set^{\mathcal{O}(X)^{op}}$ and $Top/X$. The left-adjoint, $L$, is precisely the etale space construction, whereas the right adjoint, $\Gamma$, is the "sheaf of sections" functor. $\Gamma \circ L$ is sheafification. By abstract nonsense, this adjunction restricts to an equivalence between, one one hand, the subcategory where the unit is an iso, and the other hand, the subcategory where the counit is an iso. The former is easily seen to be the category of sheaves over $X$. I know the later is the category of etale spaces over $X$, i.e. maps $Y \to X$ which are local homeomorphisms. This is traditionally proven usually an explicit description of the etale space of a sheaf, topologizing the germs of local sections etc. However, is there a way to see this at a higher level of abstraction, only appealing to the abstract definition of this induced adjunction and abstract properties of local homeomorphisms?

Comment: Look up "local homemorphism (of topoi)" in the Elephant.  It gives the topos-theoretic approach to the construction of the espace etale.

Comment: Page 651, by the by.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a sketch of why I think the condition that $Y$ is a local homeomorphism over $X$ should be sufficient for the counit to be a homeomorphism.  I haven't worked out the converse yet.

For a presheaf $F \in Set^{\mathcal{O}(X)^{op}}$, the formula for the left Kan extension should be $$L(F) = \mathrm{colim}_{y(U) \rightarrow F} U$$ where $y : \mathcal{O}(X) \rightarrow Set^{\mathcal{O}(X)^{op}}$ is the Yoneda embedding.  By Yoneda's lemma, the indexing category for the colimit is exactly the *category of elements* of $F$ which I will write as $\int F$.

Now, consider the case where $F = \Gamma_Y$ for some space $p: Y \rightarrow X$ and assume that $p$ is a local homeomorphism.  We have $\Gamma_Y(U) = \{\sigma : U \rightarrow Y | p \circ \sigma = \mathrm{id}_U \}$. So the objects in the category $\int \Gamma_Y$ are exactly the sections over the various open sets of $X$, and the morphisms are given by restriction of sections.  I'll write $d(\sigma)$ for the domain of a given section.

Our Kan extension formula becomes $$L(\Gamma_Y) = \mathrm{colim}_{\sigma \in \int \Gamma_Y} d(\sigma)$$ From here it's easy to see what the counit is: since our object is given by a colimit, it suffices to construct a map $d(\sigma) \rightarrow Y$ for each $\sigma \in \int \Gamma_Y$.  But clearly $\sigma$ itself qualifies.

Now choose an open covering $\{V_\alpha\}$ of $Y$ such that $p$ restricts to a homeomorphism on each $V_\alpha$.  We then have a collection $\{\sigma_\alpha : p(V_\alpha) \rightarrow V_\alpha\}$ of sections by choosing the inverse to each restriction.  My claim would be that this collection is cofinal (or final? I can never remember which) in the category $\int \Gamma_Y$ so that we can restrict our colimit to just this subcategory.  Notice that in this case, the components of the counit map above are homeomorphisms.

Moreover, this subcategory should also be cofinal in $\mathcal{O}(Y)$ by associating $\sigma_\alpha$ with the open set $V_\alpha$.  Then the fact that the counit is a homeomorphism should be the statement that a topological space is the colimit of any of its open coverings.

Is this along the lines of what you were thinking?

Comment: No! Please don't use "etale" to modify the word "morphism" in this context!  I'm sure you're familiar with the confusion arising from that very bad mistranslation (cf. The Elephant).  

Comment: Sorry. I did not realize this was a point of confusion.  I have changed it above.

Comment: Off topic: what is "The Elephant"?  Google only turns up novelty stories of zoo animals.

Comment: Sketches of an Elephant: A Topos Theory Compendium by Johnstone

Comment: It's a book by Peter Johnstone called "Sketches of an elephant: a topos theory compendium"

Comment: @Eric: Essentially, if you call such a morphism an $\text{\'etale}$ morphism, the word $\text{\'etale}$=slack (as in algebraic geometry or commutative algebra) loses its very specific meaning (smooth+unramified=slack).  The meaning of $\text{espace \'etal\'e}$ is "display space".  The reason this is so pernicious is that while $\text{\'etale}$ morphisms are local homeomorphisms in the $\text{\'etale}$ topology, this means nothing, since any covering morphism in any grothendieck topology trivially becomes a local homeomorphism for that topology.

Comment: Therefore, calling local homeomorphisms \'etale makes the \'etale topology have a circular definition immediately once one says that the covering families for the \'etale topology on Sch are given by jointly surjective families of \'etale morphisms.

Comment: Harry, what do you mean by "display space"? Do you mean that this is a good English translation of that French phrase, or does the phrase "display space" have some technical mathematical meaning?

Comment: @Tom: It is a good translation of espace \'etal\'e.  I mentioned it only to show that the two terms are completely unrelated in French.  One comes from the verb \'etaler, which is "to spread out" or "to display", while "\'etale" means slack (as in the tide).  I prefer the translation "spread out space", since it gives you the picture of all of the sheaf data spread out into a space, but you'd have to ask someone more knowledgeable than myself the reason why the name was chosen.  As for \'etale, I think that "slack" obviously gives the correct mental picture.

Comment: It's on page 505 of the Elephant, if you're at all curious.

Comment: Are you saying that the French verb meaning to spread out is completely unrelated to the French adjective meaning slack? I don't believe it.

Comment: @Tom I understood that étale (as slack) described the appearance of the sea (actually under a full moon) You know that smooth, almost oily part of the tidal cycle when there is hardly a ripple.  Then `spreadout' is perhaps not too far away as an image.

Comment: @Tom: Whether or not they're completely unrelated, they have been distinct words for some time now (they diverged by 1687, according to: http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/search.exe?39;s=3175247760;cat=0;m=%82tale; )

Comment: Thanks Eric, this is very helpful. Just a minor point- to make this work, I believe you need to consider the "maximal such cover", that ALL open subsets of $Y$ over which $p$ is a local homeomorphism. Otherwise I don't see how you get finality.

Comment: @Harry: That link is not working. It does not surprise me to learn that the verb and the adjective diverged centuries ago, but so what? I still don't get the point. Grothendieck adopted the French adjective etale in naming a class of morphisms that he was using; later and of course influenced by that, somebody used the participle of the French verb etaler in coining a two-word phrase denoting a very closely related geometric idea. 

Comment: @Harry: I think that your real point (which I strongly agree with!) is that it is a bad idea to use "etale map" to mean "local homeomorphism" in topology, because in algebraic geometry etale only means local homeomorphism in a very circular sense. What you also seem to say (and I disagree with this) is that anybody has been misled by a coincidental resemblance between two terms.

Comment: @Tim: My impression is that once upon a time some French-speaking mathematician, when asked to explain the non-mathematical meaning of the word "etale" to an English-speaking mathematician, had some fun, let himself go, got riffing on the "slack tide" sense of the word. The result was perpetuated by word of mouth and also in Mumford's "Red Book of Varieties and Schemes".

Comment: I have a cardboard package, labeled in French and English, from a light bulb (made in Canada, I suppose). On one side it says "angle of beam 70 degrees". On the other it says "etalement du faisceau 70 degrees".

Comment: @David: Yes, this had occurred to me.  It shouldn't change the proof much to consider all restrictions compatible with the given cover.

Comment: @Eric: Sorry for taking so long to accept this. I was away from MO for a while because of a hectic schedule!